# ARIA Live Regions and `role="alert"` not working on Mac

Tags: accessibility, voiceover, wai-aria

I am trying to get an error alert scenario working properly with assistive technology. There are two approaches i like which I am testing:

Using ARIA Live Regions

http://pauljadam.com/demos/aria-alert-validation.html

Using ARIA Alert

http://test.cita.illinois.edu/aria/alert/alert1.php

Both of this test pages work fine on Jaws 14 and VDA on PC in that the error is read outloud. However, using a Mac with voice over it does not read the errors in those examples out load.

To reproduce:

- go to http://test.cita.illinois.edu/aria/alert/alert1.php
- turn on voice over with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>
- click the guess again button after typing some numbers (the alert should be read).

Is there some non-default setting I need to be away of? Or is there a better way to do this? I'm a little surprised all theses examples do not work.

Comment: It works for me in OSX 10.9 (Mavericks), perhaps live regions  weren't supported before.

Comment: Any ideas of a setting it could be for that? I am also on OSX 10.9 and it doesnt read the alert or live....

Comment: I haven't changed the settings, I'm on the default. Just tried the alert1 page in 10.7 as well, works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution by Steve Faulkner from [Paciello Group Blog](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2012/06/html5-accessibility-chops-aria-rolealert-browser-support/) that supports Safari on Mac:

```js
function addError() {
    var elem1 = document.getElementById("add1");

    document.getElementById('add1').setAttribute("role", "alert");

    document.getElementById('display2').style.clip = 'auto';
    alertText = document.createTextNode("alert via createTextnode()");
    elem1.appendChild(alertText);
    elem1.style.display = 'none';
    elem1.style.display = 'inline';
}
```

```html
<div id="display2" role="alert"><span id="add1"></span></div>
<input type="submit" value="Method 4 alert - display" onClick="addError()">
```

Comment: Are you looking at this example from his page? http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/alert-test-4.html If so when i try it on my mac it is the same issue. If i put voice over on. And then tab to the button that opens the alert and then click it. I see the alert but voice over doesnt say anything.

Comment: Came to conclusion on this finally terms out you are right the solution is on this page. But note that the only option that did work on safari mac is option 4... http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/alert-test-4.html. I believe that before i tried this on Firefox and not safari or something because it does work.